# How can I use useState to troggle a dropdown menu by clicking a navbar item that I am getting from a looped js object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, drop-down-menu, dropdown, use-state

I made a NavBar looping an object located in an external JS file inside my project. Here is a code example of my project.

App.js File:

```
    export default function App() {
  
  // Creting useState for dropdown menu
  const [clickUser, setClickUser] = useState(true);
  const handleClick_User = useState(!clickUser);
  const closeUserMenu = () => setClickUser(true);

  

    return (
        <div className="App">
          
          {/* Passing them as props to the header */}
          <Router>
          <Header
            click_user={clickUser}
            handleClick_User={() => setClickUser(!clickUser)}
          />
          </Router>
        </div>
      );
    }
```

Now take a look to the HeaderData.js (Here I stored my NavItems):

```
    export const NavbarItems = [
  {
    text: <SearchIcon />,
    link: "/search"
  },
  {
    text: "Products",
    link: "/products"
  },
  {
    text: <PersonOutlinedIcon />,
    link: ""
  },
  {
    text: <ShoppingCartOutlinedIcon />,
    link: "/cart"
  }
];
```

So basically in the Header.js component I used map to get the navitems from the Header data shown above:

```
    function Header({ handleClick_User, closeUserMenu }) {
  return (
    <NavItems>
      {NavbarItems.map((item) => (
            <NavItem>{item.text}</NavItem>
            // if i add onClick={handleClick_User} to the navItem
            // above It will set the click event to all the items :(
      ))}
    </NavItems>
  );
}

export default Header;
```

The map is working fine, and the useState to troggle the drowdown menu is workin because I did something like this for the burger icon, my questions is how could I set the handleClick_User to trigger when clicking the User Icon in the navbar. I know I could just hard code each nav Item an that would be a solution, but I want to now if it is possible to do it this way.

Here is the code used above: https://codesandbox.io/s/sleepy-black-le6x7?file=/src/App.js:177-658

Sorry for the long question.

Comment: What are you trying to do with this line? `const handleClick_User = useState(!clickUser);`

Comment: If i add handleClick_User to an item in the navbar It will troggle the dropdown menu, I already set the container for that menu https://prnt.sc/10bn988 but I haven finish it yet.

Comment: I dont get the point of calling `useState` here instead of just directly using `!clickuser`

Comment: I can't send you a sample code without even knowing what you are doing with your code. Like I said, I don't understand the line `const handleClick_User = useState(!clickUser);`, I've never seen this being done before- why are you using useState without also assigning the function to update the state? `handleClick_User` will literally just be false the entire time? You should post a minimally reproducible example so I can understand what it is you are trying to do: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. Because as it is you are not making any sense with your question.

Comment: Are you using some sort of 3rd party library? Please post a https://codesandbox.io with a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: Hey @Nick here is my minimal reproducible example ( Sorry for not doing that in the question, next time I will keep it in mind! ) https://codesandbox.io/s/sleepy-black-le6x7?file=/src/App.js